# Android Media player by FFmpeg2.3.3 and SDL2-2.0.3 has a error when SDL_init().The error is about SDL_main.h

Tags: android, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, sdl, sdl-2

I use FFmpeg2.3.3 and SDL2-2.0.3 to develop an Android video player.I built the .apk success,but when I ran it,it's an error at SDL_init().I got message by SDL_error().The message was:

SDL_Init(14144): Application didn't initialize properly, did you include SDL_main.h in the file containing your main() function?

but I have #include "SDL_main.h" in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that ffmpeg was built with a cross-compiled SDL library? Does it show 
"SDL support    yes" in the config.log? I have been struggling with this myself. If it does indeed say "SDL support     yes" can you tell me how you did it?
another way to test is to see if you can build the ffplay binary. If you can, then again, I would really appreciate it you shared your setup and config information. I have been struggling for awhile with this.

If you are correctly building ffmpeg with a cross-compiled android compatible SDL2 library then make sure your app is using the header files from the same cross-compiled SDL2 Library.